# Cocoa error 260 During iCloud openWithCompletionHandler

Tags: synchronization, icloud

After turning iCloud off and then on I keep getting this error.  I'm issuing a query to iCloud to find the document as suggested in the docs, and it's coming back with the ubiquitous URL, so it obviously thinks the file is there, but when I try and open it with...

```
[optionsDoc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
```

I see the error...

Error 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)' during handling of AppOptions document.

In the log, and success always returns zero.

I thought maybe it just took a while to sync from iCloud after turning it on, but after waiting half an hour it's STILL giving the error.

Has anyone else seen this?  Any suggestions?

Thanks
Ray

Comment: Are you using a  nsfilecoordinator as per the iCloud document handling guidelines?

Comment: Omg, I can't believe I didn't see that.  I added a file co-ordinator on this and my other reads, but now I'm a little concerned... I usually update using...

        [optionsDoc updateChangeCount:UIDocumentChangeDone];

How does this get co-ordinated?  The documentation says that the save takes place as and when the OS thinks is appropriate.

Comment: This also raises a few other questions.  Do I need to manually save my documents using saveToUrl instead of using updateChangeCount when using iCloud so I can use the file co-ordinator?  Also, UIDocument keeps the document open after reading and saving which is a problem if you have more than one application accessing the same container.  If the UIDocument is closed, does it still continue to monitor notifications for changes from documentStateChanged?

Comment: Actually not sure you need the nsfilecoordinator if you are using UIDocument.  I think maybe UIDocument handles this for you - its been a while since I did this stuff so you best review the documentation carefully.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald. thanks a lot.  I remove nsfilecoordinator, and error 260 is gone.